# c# Asp.net getting Cookie expiration time set in javascript always returns 01.01.0001

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, date, cookies

I use a javascript function to store the cookie:

```
createCookie("teaser", "teaser", 7);
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
var expires = "";
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
return value;
}
```

And when I check the cookies in my browser the cookie expiration of teaser is correctly set: 
25. oktober 2011 16:12:17

But when in C# i go to get the value, the expiration date is set to 01.01.0001.

```
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["teaser"];
    if (cookie != null && teaserList.Count() > 0)
    {

        cookie.Expires is 01.01.0001
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Egghead says that:](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/198ce250-59da-4388-89e5-fce33d725aa7/aspnet-cookies-faq.aspx)

> The browser is responsible for managing cookies, and the cookie's
>   expiration time and date help the browser manage its store of cookies.
>   Therefore, although you can read the name and value of a cookie, you
>   cannot read the cookie's expiration date and time. When the browser
>   sends cookie information to the server, the browser does not include
>   the expiration information. (The cookie's Expires property always
>   returns a date-time value of zero.) If you are concerned about the
>   expiration date of a cookie, you must reset it.

Answer (score 4):

The browser does not transmit the expiration date of a cookie to servers, this is as per HTTP specification.

Browsers only send the cookie name and value **only**.

The Expires property on the cookie object is only used when *setting* expiration date on a cookie that is going to be *written* in a response, not *read* in a request.

When reading the cookie is Expires property value is always going to be null. You can see this for yourself by examining the HTTP headers. If you really want to read the expire value of a cookie, try writing it in the value itself, or using another cookie with the value of the expiration date (you will need to keep them in sync yourself).

Comment: Ah...good to know. I was having a case of "Cookie bites man".