# ASP.NET MVC User Authentication expiration time

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to return User Authentication expiration time via an AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AuthenticationExpiration()
{
    return Content(HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"].Expires.ToString();)
}
```

View:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("get time", "AuthenticationExpiration", new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "expirationTimeBox"})
<span id="expirationTimeBox"></span>
```

**UPDATE 1**

Be attentive to your forms authentication configuration:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Login" protection="All" timeout="500" slidingExpiration="true">
   </forms>
</authentication>
```

If your slidingExpiration property setted to true - cookie lifetime will be extended.

**UPDATE 2**

I found solution for constant DateTime.Min value of expiration: http://forums.asp.net/p/1158239/1920541.aspx#1920541

**UPDATE 3**

Sorry, from beginning I was confused by goal to get expiration date by using ajax call. It is wrong solution, as we see. More native and correct would be working with javascript, BUT it is impossible, if to believe to what I've seen:

[Reading cookie expiration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532193/reading-cookie-expiration-date)

[c# Asp.net getting Cookie expiration time set in javascript always returns 01.01.0001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809072/c-sharp-asp-net-getting-cookie-expiration-time-set-in-javascript-always-returns)

The only solution what I saw is to set expiration date of .ASPXAUTH cookie to separate cookie value, when you call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, isPersistent);` to `DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(//... your expiration, that's in web.config);`.

Comment: Wouldn't making that additional request extent the expiration time?

Comment: Even if it extends, there are no other way to get some data except requesting the web server. But expiration is absolute value and it isn't calculated since last request time.

Comment: HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"].Expires.ToString() - call constantly returns a value = DateTime.MinValue, so I've used FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"].Value).Expiration.ToString() but can you confirm that this is the same?

Comment: Concerning UPDATE 2: It means that this bug is still in the ASP.NET even 4.0?

Comment: FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"].Value).Expi‌​ration.ToString() - works pretty well so I'm cool! Thanks!