# How to get cookies time and perform autologin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, model-view-controller

I am working on a DOT NET Core project in which I have to perform the task of auto-login. I have tried several ways but did not find the solution.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync(myLoginModel lm){
if (lm.IsRemember)
{
CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
Response.Cookies.Append("UserEmail", lm.Email, option);
Response.Cookies.Append("UserPassword", lm.Password, option);
Response.Cookies.Append("IsRemember", lm.IsRemember.ToString(), option);
}
}
```

Now during 10-days if the user opens the website, I want to redirect to the DASHBOARD PAGE Directly.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
string IsRemember= Request.Cookies["IsRemember"];
if (IsRemember== "True")
{
lm.Email = Request.Cookies["UserEmail"];
lm.Password = Request.Cookies["UserPassword"];
 //Check if user visited the website during 10 days of time then redirect to DASHBOARD PAGE.        
}
}
```

I have tried many ways in which the below code is one of them but did not get the perfect solution.

Tried Way 1

```
 foreach (HttpCookie thisCookie in this.Request.Cookies)
{
if (thisCookie.Expires < DateTime.Now)
{
// expired
}
}
```

Tried Way 2

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserEmail"].Expires.ToString() < DateTime.Now) 
{ 
                    
}
```

Comment: You are introducing a security flaw by storing the password in the cookie. Is there a token that can validate an authenticated user? That's the value that should be stored in the cookie with your 10-day expiration. This way, when they request the login page, you can just check if that cookie value is still valid and redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not read the cookies expiration date. Please refer: ([c# Asp.net getting Cookie expiration time set in javascript always returns 01.01.0001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809072/c-sharp-asp-net-getting-cookie-expiration-time-set-in-javascript-always-returns))

So you need to change your approach like following way.

Add Remember Time in Cookies.

```
Response.Cookies.Append("RememberTime", DateTime.Now(), option);
```

And read this RememberTime Cookies value and write your logic for check with as per you requirement day.

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Cookies["RememberTime"]).AddDays(10) > DateTime.Now)
```